# What am I riddle? I exist just before your eyes

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I exist just before your eyes but you can't touch me
> You can be anywhere but I will be nowhere
> I can be bought but no one truly owns me
> People buy me but I don't truly exist
> I am 3 on a 2
> Some consider me an investment some consider me nothing
> Some say I am the future, some say I am just a trend with an end

Hint

> I have 9 letters

Hint 2

> "I am 3 on a 2" you are looking at this.

Hint 3

> I am a type of NFT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

> metaverse

I exist just before your eyes but you can't touch me

> metaverse is virtual

You can be anywhere but I will be nowhere

> you can go anywhere in the metaverse but it isn't really anywhere

I can be bought but no one truly owns me

> metaverse is virtual, can be bought but not truly owned

People buy me but I don't truly exist

> metaverse is virtual, doesn't actually exist in the real world, everything in it can be bought but not owned

I am 3 on a 2

> 3D world on a 2D screen that you're looking at

Some consider me an investment some consider me nothing

> metaverse property could be an investment, but others think it's worth nothing

Some say I am the future, some say I am just a trend with an end

> some say metaverse is the future (i.e. Facebook), some say it will go away

Hint

> *I have 9 letters*
>  9 letters in "metaverse"

Hint 2

> *"I am 3 on a 2" you are looking at this.*
>  3D world on a 2D screen that you're looking at

Hint 3

> I am a type of NFT
>  Metaverse property runs on NFT

Comment: The "I am 3 on a 2" refers to "And 3d world on a 2d screen". But good job.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> an [NFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fungible_token)?

---

*I exist just before your eyes but you can't touch me

You can be anywhere but I will be nowhere*

> People can buy NFTs for pretty much anything, but it's a data-based abstraction rather than a physical reality.

*I can be bought but no one truly owns me

People buy me but I don't truly exist*

> Again, people spend money on these things, but they don't really exist, they're just a way of granting some abstract rights.

*I am 3 on a 2*

> This is probably the [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay) part?

*Some consider me an investment some consider me nothing

Some say I am the future, some say I am just a trend with an end*

> Some people see value in NFTs and think they're the future of trading. Others think they're a pointless fad which will soon be over.

---

Much of this could actually apply to any sort of

> financial abstraction, including stock market options or even money itself.

Comment: rot13(Lbh tbg n unys bs gur nafjre. Gur nafjre vf zber fcrpvsvp.)

Comment: rot13(Gur "V nz 3 ba n 2" unf n qrsvavgvba gung fubhyq or hapbirerq. Nsgre lbh trg gur nafjre vg jvyy znxr zber frafr.)

Comment: rot13("V nz 3 ba n 2" pbhyq zrna gur chmmyr vf ersreevat gb Ovgpbva, jubfr flzoby vf n pncvgny O jvgu gjb iregvpny yvarf guebhtu vg (yvxr n qbyyne fvta), juvpu xvaq bs ybbxf yvxr gur ahzore 3 ba gbc bs n ebzna ahzreny 2.)

Comment: @SQLnoob Sorry for slow reply ... it was a good idea, but the OP's edit/hint seems to disprove it.

Answer (score 3):

Real wacky but just as a thought:

> Australia

*I can be bought but no one truly owns me

People buy me but I don't truly exist*

> Here is the main idea: Australia is a corporate state.
>  It is a Form 18-K United States SEC registered entity.
>  This allows the Nation of Australia to issue securities in the US market.
>  But no one really owns it. You can buy the securities, but can't own
>  Australia

*I exist just before your eyes but you can't touch me.

You can be anywhere but I will be nowhere*

> Only if you are in Australia since
>  it's a country, and thus not a tangible thing

*I am 3 on a 2*

> Referring to number of elements on the modern and old flags: the Union Jack,
>  the Commonwealth Star and the Southern Cross, and just union jack and the
>  star on the old one.
>  or 3 colors on the 2 color background

*Some consider me an investment some consider me nothing

Some say I am the future, some say I am just a trend with an end*

> Talking about the longest running period of economic growth without
>  a recession.

Comment: yes yes yes yes this is actually amazing

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Great thinking with this answer. If you are interested on learning more about puzzling SE (and earning your first badge) check out the tour at this link: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Wow this fits perfectly but this is not the answer in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Bitcoin?

*I exist just before your eyes but you can't touch me*

*You can be anywhere but I will be nowhere*

> You can see it on a screen anywhere, but it doesn't truly 'exist'.

*I can be bought but no one truly owns me*

*People buy me but I don't truly exist*

> People can by bitcoin but it doesn't give them something physical to own.

*I am 3 on a 2*

> This could be talking about how bitcoin changes price and so it can be worth 3, on the second day maybe?

*Some consider me an investment some consider me nothing*

> Some people invest in bitcoin while others don't care/ know about it.

*Some say I am the future, some say I am just a trend with an end*

> Some people say bitcoin is the future of currency.

Comment: In my hint I mention "I have 9 letters", "Bitcoin" has 7.

Comment: I do see that my answer doesn't align with the hint now.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> Zuck Bucks

I exist just before your eyes but you can't touch me

> zuck bucks are virtual

You can be anywhere but I will be nowhere

> you can take zuck bucks anywhere but they're nowhere

I can be bought but no one truly owns me

> you can buy zuck bucks but don't really own them

People buy me but I don't truly exist

> you can buy zuck bucks but it doesn't really exist, it's virtual

I am 3 on a 2

> Under Section 3(a)(2), a "bank" is defined broadly to mean any national bank, or any banking institution organized under the law. Zuck bucks is like this

Some consider me an investment some consider me nothing

> some think zuck bucks could be an investment, others think it's worth nothing

Some say I am the future, some say I am just a trend with an end

> some say zuck bucks are the future (i.e. Facebook), some say it will go away

Hint

> *I have 9 letters*
>  9 letters in "zuck bucks"

Hint 2

> *"I am 3 on a 2" you are looking at this.*
>  Under Section 3(a)(2), a "bank" is defined broadly to mean any national bank, or any banking institution organized under the law. Zuck Bucks is like this

Hint 3

> I am a type of NFT
>  Zuck Bucks is an NFT